# Meaning of these Closure Abbreviations

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

What do these closure abbreviations stand for in Mathematical Logic?

Semantic Closure:  **Con**($\Gamma$)

Syntactic Closure:  **Ded**($\Gamma$)

...where $\Gamma$ is a set of well-formed formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\text {Con}(\Gamma)$ is the set of all formulas that are [logical **Con**sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) of the set (of formulas) $\Gamma$.

$\text {Ded}(\Gamma)$ is the set of all formulas that are *derivable* from the set (of formulas) $\Gamma$, i.e. there is a **Ded**uction of them by way of the [*proof system*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_calculus).

Comment: Okay, so **Con** comes from Logical **Con**sequence. Why is the other one **Ded** instead of **Der** from **Der**ivation?

Comment: @A_for_Abacus - **Ded** for Deduction.

Comment: So deductions of $\Gamma$ is the same meaning as derivations of $\Gamma$?

Comment: @A_for_Abacus - Yes; see e.g [Natural Deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction) and [Derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction#Hypothetical_derivations).